# No audio Dell XPS 9730, while the audio works just fine in the live USB Kubundu 22.04

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, kde, alsa

When using the live USB, it works just fine.

Outputs for the live USB:

```bash
kubuntu@kubuntu:~$ inxi -xA
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel vendor: Dell driver: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl
    bus-ID: 0000:00:1f.3
  Device-2: Logitech HD Pro Webcam C920 type: USB
    driver: snd-usb-audio,uvcvideo bus-ID: 3-4.3.2:18
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.19.0-32-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
```

```
kubuntu@kubuntu:~$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: sofsoundwire [sof-soundwire], device 0: Jack Out (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofsoundwire [sof-soundwire], device 2: Speaker (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofsoundwire [sof-soundwire], device 5: HDMI 1 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofsoundwire [sof-soundwire], device 6: HDMI 2 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofsoundwire [sof-soundwire], device 7: HDMI 3 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

For the installed system:

```
~$ inxi -xA
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel vendor: Dell driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel
    bus-ID: 0000:00:1f.3
  Device-2: Logitech HD Pro Webcam C920 type: USB
    driver: snd-usb-audio,uvcvideo bus-ID: 3-4.3.2:7
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.19.0-32-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: no
```

> Note that PipeWire is not running, it was one of the "fixes" I attempted, but it doesn't work with it running neither.

```
~$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 11: HDMI 5 [HDMI 5]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 12: HDMI 6 [HDMI 6]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 13: HDMI 7 [HDMI 7]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 14: HDMI 8 [HDMI 8]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 15: HDMI 9 [HDMI 9]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 16: HDMI 10 [HDMI 10]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 17: HDMI 11 [HDMI 11]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

For both:

The driver shown in alsamixer is `Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Version k5.19.0-32-generic.`.

The kernel is `5.19.0-32-generic`

Disabled secure boot.

...

Comment: Fair point, @guiverc.

It's Kubuntu 22.04

And I'm bamboozled at the moment, because that kernel actually doesn't play along with the nvidia drivers, not even the dkms ones, so I'm completely out of my depth again, because I can't get the audio to work with any other kernel, and I can't get the graphics card to work with that kernel.

Answer (score 1):

Got it to work

> While filling all of this, I gathered all the drivers I had blacklisted with no effect in the `alsa.conf` and realized I had not blacklisted `snd-intel-dspcfg`. I tried that, and audio is just fine now.

The contents of my `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa.conf`:

```
options snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl index=3 enabled=1
options snd-sof-pci-intel-tgl index=2 enabled=1
blacklist snd-intel-dspcfg
```

> I got to say that the high standards that stack exchange has for questions are helpful in unimaginable ways. I solved the problem just because I wanted to make sure I fully documented my troubleshooting process.

Edit: Now comes the catch, I just realized that with this Kernel, I'm completely out of my depth about getting the graphics drivers to load. So, back to square one.

Answer (score 0):

### Update

Since kernel `6.5.1` the sound works as expected. Until release of Ubuntu 23.10, which will ship with `6.5` kernel, i only see the option of switching temporarily to a running release distro like `NixOs unstable` or `Arch`.

### Original Answer

Install Ubuntu 22.04 LTS without internet connection, update afterwards and boot with kernel `5.19.0-32-generic`.

**tldr;**

Unfortunately, [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1468092/1715483) did't fixed it for me.

I've found out that when booting with the kernel of the live-image, the sound worked again. Didn't test all versions, but `5.19.0-32-generic` worked for me. The current LTS kernel `5.19.0-46-generic` did not.

To do this, install Ubuntu 22.04 LTS without internet connection to install it with the working kernel. Update afterwards. During boot, select *Advanced Options for Ubuntu* and then the older kernel. If this works for you, you can adapt grub to always use this kernel.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instructions mentioned here https://github.com/thesofproject/sof-bin. It worked like a charm for my Dell XPS 17 9730.